# Python script can write to file but same line can't do it later in the code

Tags: python

At the start of the code when I write in the string:

```
                        #write username and skill level to file
                    f = open("ArenaList.txt","a")
                    f.write(user + " " + str(health) + '\n')
                    Parent.RemovePoints(user, settings["cost"])
                    f.close()
```

That works perfectly fine.

Later in the code, I'm trying to find a certain line containing a username and whatever it's health is, then edit the health value, it can't write at all, and I cant figure out why:

```
                                with open("ArenaList.txt","r") as search:
                                    for line in search:
                                            if user in line:
                                                    strLine = ("{}".format(line))
                                                    health = (("{}".format(line)).split(' ', 1)[-1])
                                                    name = (("{}".format(line)).split(' ')[0])
                                                    inthealth = int(health)
                                                    inthealth = (inthealth + 5)
                                                    Parent.SendTwitchMessage(user + " " + str(inthealth))
                                                    search.write(user + " " + str(inthealth) + '\n')

                                            else:
                                                    search.close()
```

Error I get is "Can not write to file ArenaList.txt"

Thanks for the help!
Edit: Realized im stupid and the bit that opens the file is "r" for read. I don't know how to make it able to both read and write though.

Comment: How about you open the file in write mode? `'w'`

Comment: Using a text file open for read and write is very hard.  You need to research binary random access files (or just use a database).

Answer (score 0):

you have to read a file, and then write to it (overwriting any existing data), without closing and reopening:

```
with open("ArenaList.txt","r+") as search:
    # some code
    # now to write do this
    search.seek(0)
    search.write("something")
```

Comment: that mostly worked, but now it spams the line it needs to write at the bottom of the file rather than overwriting the correct line

Comment: for your use case remove search.seek(0) and try.